# AngularJS validate other field when this field changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

So, I've got a select menu with some options, and a text field that takes in a number.  I need the text field to have certain ranges depending on the value of the select menu, which I have all set up with a custom validation.  What I can't figure out is, how do I force that validation to run when the option of the select menu changes?

I tried directly in the HTML to do:

```
<select ng-change="$scope.my_form.numberField.$validate()">
```

This didn't work, so I created a created a function in the controller to run:

```
$scope.myFunction = function(){
    $scope.my_form.numberField.$validate();
}
```

Then changed the select to

```
<select ng-change="myFunction()">
```

I then tried changing the function code to:

```
console.log( $scope.my_form.numberField.$validate() );
```

This is spits out an "undefined"

The HTML text field looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="numberField" ng-model="numberField" number-validate>
```

I really have no idea where else to go from here.  The validation works perfectly as I update the field directly, but I can't figure out how to get it to update when the select field changes.  Any ideas?

Comment: please update the question with your text filed html tag you are using.

Comment: I added the text field above.

Comment: You may have a look at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-validate/.

Comment: I prefer a vanilla AngularJS solution if possible, and/or an explanation of why what I'm attempting to do won't work.  I've found a couple of similar issues where this was the recommended way of going about this, but I just can't get it working.

Comment: If possible change the type to number and try min, max attribute

Comment: I could change it to number if that would help, but the min and max values depend on the option selected with the select field.

Comment: I tried changing the input type to number, and added min and max values, though nothing has changed.  When I select an option, then fill in the text field, the validation works and my messages display appropriately.  The problem is that I need the select field to also invoke the validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my current solution.  I still feel like calling $validation() should work and that I missed something, so if anyone knows what the problem with that is, please share.

I changed my directive to add a $watchCollection and included both of the fields that I wanted to track.

Originally I had something like this:

```
App.directive('numberValidate', function() {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
            var selectField = scope.my_form.selectField
```

I changed that to something like this:

```
App.directive('numberValidate', function() {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.$watchCollection('[my_form.numberField, my_form.selectField]', function (data) {
            var numberField = data[0];
            var selectField = data[1];
```

This still requires having number-validate in the html:

```
<input type="text" name="numberField" ng-model="my_form.numberField" number-validate>
```

I'm fairly new to Angular, so I'm not sure if this is the best option, but it's working right now.